# find occurrences count in json object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "resourceAttributes": {
            "siteId": "100"
        },
},
{
        "id": 2,
        "resourceAttributes": {
            "siteId": "200"
        },
},
{
        "id": 3,
        "resourceAttributes": {
            "siteId": "100"
        },
},
```

I have this kind of json and as a result I want to show output like this

```
SiteId100 occurance 2
SiteId200 occurance 1
```

this out put is on basis of occurrences of site id value like if siteId 100 values occurred in 2 objects I need to show number of occurrences with count. I am trying something like getting all possible site ids and then removing duplicates and then finding one by one but seems that is not a neat solution.

Comment: Please provide what you tried and show what you get vs. what you expected, or point out what about it you think is "not neat". Also note that what you provided is just the data, no code was provided - and the data is not a valid json object (it's probably missing a set of outer curly braces, or only showing part of a larger data structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use colections.Counter. here's the full code:

```
from collections import Counter

data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
            "resourceAttributes": {
                "siteId": "100"
            },
    },
    {
            "id": 2,
            "resourceAttributes": {
                "siteId": "200"
            },
    },
    {
            "id": 3,
            "resourceAttributes": {
                "siteId": "100"
            },
    }
]

c = Counter(s.get("resourceAttributes").get("siteId") for s in data)

for k, v in c.items():
    print("siteId{} occurance:  {}".format(k, v))
```

output:

siteId100 occurance:  2

siteId200 occurance:  1